# How can I make a website partially unsecure?

Tags: http, sockets, websocket, https

I have a website that uses HTTPS so it is secure by default.

I am aiming to send some HTTP requests from the website, but the problem is that modern versions of web browsers do not allow the use of HTTP requests inside of HTTPS sites.

So, what I am trying to do here is to make a portion of my website un-secure using HTTP instead of HTTPS, so that I can send the requests I want.

Is that possible?

If there are any other suggestions to send HTTP requests, please help me with it.

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion: **do not use HTTP without S**. Why would you choose an unsecure channel over a secure one? You ask for trouble.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Should you? No. Instead, let unsecured connection go through a proxy, so that you make a secured connection with this proxy and the proxy makes the request to the unsecured connection. This might be possible on your existing server that already is accessed via HTTPS. How exactly depends entirely on the tech stack you are using.

Comment: You can make the other part HTTPS

Comment: *"I am aiming to send some HTTP requests from the website, but the problem is that modern versions of web browsers do not allow the use of HTTP requests inside of HTTPS sites."* - It is not quite clear what you want to do. But if you want to access a resource from the server side backend of your web application, then it is irrelevant what the browser does. The browser can still access your site using HTTPS, while your backend is accessing another resource using plain HTTP.